# Can i pass parameters to a windows service through GPO

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-service

We have a custom windows service written in C++. This windows service runs in all the VMs in a particular domain. I have a requirement to pass certain parameters to that windows service which the service should read during startup. Is it possible to do this through GPO or some other technique should be used?

Comment: You could set a Registry value that the service reads during startup and which you can set via GPOs.

Comment: By default GPOs are processed async, so there is no guarantee that the GPO sets the registry key at the logon. Depends on your setup, if that has an impact. Otherwise set the GPO processing to synchronously (which has other drawbacks).